# Change Python Version in SublimeText2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, anaconda

I'm almost going crazy trying to figure this out, but I know I'm close.

I want to change the Python used by SublimeText2

I'm running Python in ST2, but it is not the version I want.

```
import sys
print sys.executable

>>>> /usr/bin/python
```

The version I want is in the terminal.

```
me_user$ which python

>>>> //anaconda/bin/python
```

I want to use the Anaconda python in ST2, not the /usr/bin/python.

But I cannot figure out how to change the path in ST2 to read the Anaconda version of python.

Any help?

..... UPDATE .....

I followed the instructions by Jerome but now I get an error.

Here is my build path:

```
{
    "path": "/anaconda/bin/python",
    "cmd": ["python2.7", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

And here is the error:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

[Errno 20] Not a directory
[cmd:  [u'python2.7', u'/Users/robertdefilippi/Desktop/test2.py']]
[dir:  /Users/robertdefilippi/Desktop]
[path: /anaconda/bin/python]
[Finished]
```

What have I done wrong now?

Comment: http://robinwragg.tumblr.com/post/55364315373/how-to-specify-which-python-version-sublime-text-2

Comment: Just updated my code. The instructions did not work :/

Answer (score 1):

Ah figured it out.

I used:

```
echo $PATH
```

In the terminal to get the full range of paths.

I then copied the paths into

> ```
> {
>      "path": "PATH",
>      "cmd": ["python2.7", "$file"],
>      "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
>      "selector": "source.python"  }
> ```

And it works :)